# Is killing monsters with magic considered to be breaking the first law of magic?

Tags: the-dresden-files

What about halfbreeds? I find it a bit subjective on what is the difference between, say, frying a fey to death and frying a human to death, with magic.

Is the difference having a human soul? How would one recognize the possession of a human soul in a creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the first book, [Storm Front](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Front), our first encounter with the First Law:

> And someone had used magic to do it. They had used magic to wreak harm on another, violating the First Law.

But Harry indicates that the laws only apply to Mortals, as we see a few chapters later, when Morgan prepares to kill him with the following pronouncement:

> "Harry Blackstone Copperfield Dresden. Irresponsible use of true names for summoning and binding others to your will violates the Fourth Law of Magic," the man intoned. "I remind you that you are under the Doom of Damocles. No further violations of the Laws will be tolerated. The sentence for further violation is death, by the sword, to be carried out at once."

Harry's Response:

> "Evening, Morgan. **You know as well as I do that those laws apply to mortals.** Not faeries. Especially for something as trivial as I just did. And I didn't break the Fourth Law. He had the choice whether to take my deal or not."

And, lest we wonder if Harry is correct, Morgan isn't happy about it, but confirms this:

> "That's a technicality, Dresden. A pair of them."

The laws apply to Human->Human interaction; what is done to fairies and other creatures is out of the scope of the White Council's authority.  Now, what the Fey QUEENS might have to say is another matter.

What constitutes human is also pretty flexible; Vampires, in many cases, WERE human, but don't count.  The same being true of Werewolves and others.  Interpreting the law is often left to the wardens and the Council itself; only in the case of clear, true humans, is it cut and dry.

Also, remember -- the laws are NOT about justice; as they point out in [Turn Coat](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Turn_Coat), the laws are about restraining the use of power.  Said restraint is primarily to protect humans and other wizards; the various other beings are left to fend for themselves.